# Homomorphisms from a linear algebraic group to a finite group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Is there any example of a linear algebraic group (over an algebraically closed field) $G$, a finite group $H$ (with discrete topology) and a group homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ which is not continuous, or at least not a morphism of (affine) varieties? If there exist such examples, is there any criterion for checking whether a given group homomorphism is also a morphism of algebraic groups?

Comment: Not continuous in which topology?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Zariski topology on $G$ and $H$, where we view $H$ as a linear algebraic group via a faithful representation $H\rightarrow GL_n$. I believe that makes $H$ a discrete topological space.

Comment: You should edit your question to make this clear and also include your thoughts about the problem.